# breezejs: calling savecChanges for a classic ODATA service fails

Tags: javascript, breeze

I'm trying to save an Entity that was loaded using a classic WEBAPI ODATA service.

When saveChanges is called on the client side, the modified entity is found and then the code goes into ´createChangeRequests´ and because the entityState is modified it goes into the function :

```
 function updateDeleteMergeRequest(request, aspect, prefix) {
    var extraMetadata = aspect.extraMetadata;
    var uri = extraMetadata.uri;
    if (__stringStartsWith(uri, prefix)) {
        uri = uri.substring(prefix.length);
    }
    request.requestUri = uri;
    if (extraMetadata.etag) {
        request.headers["If-Match"] = extraMetadata.etag;
    }
}
```

However it raises an exception on the second line because extraMetadata is null. Where is this supposed to come from  ? The property extraMetadata does not even exist on 'aspect'....

breeze does have metadata of my model since I can load entities. It's just that I cannot save.

Answer (score 1):

line 13318(breeze.debug.js):

```
    function mergeEntity(node, mappingContext, meta) {
      node._$meta = meta;
      meta.extra = node.__metadata;//added
      var em = mappingContext.entityManager;
```

Comment: Is that a bug fix ?  Is it going to make it to next release ?

Answer (score 0):

I just stumpled across the same problem with Breeze 1.4.13. I resolved the problem by adding meta.extraMetadata = node.__metadata in line 14396

```
function mergeEntity(mc, node, meta) {
    node._$meta = meta;
    meta.extraMetadata = node.__metadata;
    var em = mc.entityManager;
```

Comment: This isn't really "solving" anything IMO. Eliminating the exception doesn't get at the root cause which is that the "extra metadata" are missing and we don't know why. We have to find out why. When we know why - perhaps the Web API isn't sending the "__metadata" property - , we can determine the proper course of action. I'm looking into it.

Comment: **See related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24782426/breeze-js-for-sharepoint-2013-error-saving-changes**

Comment: Well, I'm rather new to breeze, but as far as I understand the meta-object is missung the extraMetadata the node already has. I don't know from the top of my hat how the extraMetadata is supposed to be provided to the meta-object, but as far as I figured this is needed by the sharepoint-adapter to create the needed http-body for sharepoint.