# breezejs: __stringStartsWith is undefined when using ODATA adapter

Tags: javascript, breeze

I use a WCF Data Service and when I try to save an entity, I get the error `__stringStartsWith is undefined`. It raises the exception in the file breeze.dataService.odata.js at line 215.

I've included both breeze.debug.js and breeze.dataService.odata.js in my page. That function is defined in the breeze.debug.js as a global function, so I guess it should be known by the dataService adapter... Is there something I'm missing here ?

**EDIT**

client:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ed0o7ie1n88pnlw/reprobreezee_client.zip

service:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vnye10lcgg4h3iu/reprobreeze_service.zip

Comment: Sorry, need more information.

Comment: I understand. I've put together a repro. There's two zips. One for the ODATA service and one for the js client (just browse to /app/index.html. Note that the breeze version was modified using the fix suggested in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513334/breezejs-calling-savecchanges-for-a-classic-odata-service-fails

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with `__stringStartsWith` in the `breeze.dataService.odata.js` file being `undefined` when trying to insert a record.

Change code from

```
if (__stringStartsWith(uri,prefix)) ...
```

to

```
if (core.stringStartsWith(uri, prefix)) ...
```