# Import entities from local storage when using ASP.NET WebApi OData not loading extra metadata

Tags: angularjs, breeze

When I try to save imported entities from local storage it thrown exception here.

```
    var extraMetadata = aspect.extraMetadata;
    var uri = extraMetadata.uri || extraMetadata.id;
    if (core.stringStartsWith(uri, baseUri)) {
        uri = routePrefix + uri.substring(baseUri.length);
    }
    request.requestUri = uri;
    if (extraMetadata.etag) {
        request.headers["If-Match"] = extraMetadata.etag;
    }
```

But if I get data from OData service directly it is saving correctly. Anything I am missing when importing data from local storage. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513334/breezejs-calling-savecchanges-for-a-classic-odata-service-fails) solution but it didn't help me.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: extraMetadata undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug we are tracking (#2574). I was hoping we'd fix it for v.1.4.12 but it looks like it will have to wait a cycle.

There is no good workaround. You can try to remember the `extraMetadata` yourself (in some sideband storage) and re-attach it when you re-import. Not fun I know.  Sorry.