# Breeze.JS for SharePoint 2013 error saving changes

Tags: breeze, sharepoint-2013

The object `extraMetadata` is undefined and throwing an error on line 247 of `breeze.labs.dataservice.sharepoint.js`

```
rawEntity.__metadata = { 'type': aspect.extraMetadata.type };
```

I suspect it is because I have not defined the type found in `__metadata` object on my entity definitions for breeze. Any suggestions on how to define my type correctly would be very welcome! Here is my type definition for one of the objects.

```
   models.Project = {
        name: 'Project',
        defaultResourceName: 'getbytitle(\'Projects\')/items',
        dataProperties: {
            ID: {
                type: breeze.DataType.Int32
            },
            Title: {
                nullable: false
            },
            StatusId: {
                type: breeze.DataType.Int32,
                nullable: false
            },
            SelectedApproverId: {
                type: breeze.DataType.Int32,
                nullable: false
            },
            Created: {
                type: breeze.DataType.DateTime
            },
            Modified: {
                type: breeze.DataType.DateTime
            }
        },
        navigationProperties: {
            Status: {
                type: "Status",
                foreignKeyNames: ['StatusId'],
                hasMany: false
            },
            SelectedApprover: {
               type: "User",
               foreignKeyNames: ["SelectedApproverId"]
            }
        }
    };
```

**UPDATE: 11/11/2013**

If I run the following query:

```
    return breeze.EntityQuery
           .from(metadataStore.getEntityType('Project').defaultResourceName)
           .orderBy('Created desc')
           .using(manager)
           .execute()
           .then(function (data) {
                console.log(data.results);
                return data.results;
           });
```

the results are an array of simple JavaScript objects, not Breeze Entities, that lack an `__metadata` properties. I'm trying to figure out why this is the case.

**Update: 11/12/2014**

I have confirmed that this issue presents itself when I have multiple entities defined under `navigationProperties`.

Comment: I Haven't used that adapter before but I noticed your title has no type attribute - copy paste error?

Comment: No, the default is string and Title is string.

Comment: Hmm gotcha, how are you getting to the error?  I assume when performing a query, if so can you call the `toType` method on your query and let breeze know which type of entity is being returned?  If it is not within the context of a query then I would defer to someone who has used that adapter before.

Comment: It's not in Breeze itself but in the SharePoint data adapter. When saving changes SharePoint's web service expects an object called __metadata and the adapter is attempting to build it but the `type` property on `extraMetadata` is undefined. It's not directly related to SP but to `breeze.labs.dataservice.sharepoint`. Breeze is working exactly as expected. Queries are fine, etc.

Comment: Sorry I re-read the question body and forgot the title about saveChanges not while querying : )  My bust man.

Comment: No problem. I think my question is in fact a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513334/breezejs-calling-savecchanges-for-a-classic-odata-service-fails

Comment: Depending on the version of breeze you are using you would expect that this would have been corrected by now if it were indeed an issue.  Being that you are using the SharePoint adapter it seems you are using a fairly new version so I would leave the question open and see if IdeaBlade have a better explanation.

Comment: I apologize that this is still floating out there. I've figured out what the problem is. If I am selecting too many fields from the SP list, the adapter is returning POJOs with no `__metadata`.

Answer (score 3):

> Please be sure you are using BreezeJS v.1.4.12 or later.

To be clear, the code to which you refer is on **line 147** (not 247) of the *breeze.labs.dataservice.sharepoint.js* file in my possession.

It's located within the `_createChangeRequest` where it is **preparing to save a modified entity**. I'll assume that you have queried a `Product` entity, made changes to it, and are saving it back when the error occurs.

I don't believe the problem will be traced to how you defined the metadata for your `Product` type.

**You should NOT define a `__metadata` property for your type**. The `__metadata` property is something we expect SharePoint (any OData source in fact) to add to the JSON entity data that it sends to the client when you query that OData source for entities.

> `__metadata` wouldn't be defined for results returned by a projection but then your issue concerns a *modified entity* so I'm assuming that you acquired this entity through a normal query ... one that did not have a `select` clause.

**I'd like to know if you see the `__metadata` property in the JSON payload of a query that retrieved the entity you were modifying. Please examine the network traffic from the query request.**  If you don't see it there, we have to find out why the server didn't send it.

### Background

The `__metadata` property on the JSON node is a crucial part of the contract with the SharePoint OData server. That's how the Breeze client learns about the entity's type and its etag.

Look at the `jsonResultsAdapter.visitNode` and `updateEntityNode` methods. You'll see how the adapter uses `__metadata` to determine the `EntityType` for that data. You'll also see that the adapter moves the `__metadata` to the adapter result's `extraMetadata` property. BreezeJS subsequently moves that "extra metadata" from this result object to the entity's `entityAspect.extraMetadata` property.

Does this seem tortured? It *is* tortured. OData requires extra information to be carried around with the entity (specifically the etag) without which the server simply will not update or delete the entity. We have to squirrel that info away somewhere, out of your hair, and then bring it back when we make save requests to the server. We put it on the `entityAspect` in keeping with that property's role as the keeper of the "entity-ness" that has nothing to do with your object's *business purpose* and everything to do with how it is persisted.

So much for the *why*. Where is the bug?

### The bug

The underlying bug is that this `__metadata` from the SharePoint OData source has disappeared. We don't know how it disappeared yet. But we're in big trouble without it.

The sharepoint adapter should give a better message when `extraMetadata` is missing. We actually look for that problem a few lines later; see `adjustUpdateDeleteRequest`:

```
var extraMetadata = aspect.extraMetadata;
if (!extraMetadata) {
    throw new Error("Missing the extra metadata for an update/delete entity");
}
```

That test appears too late. I'll make a note to move the test up.

But such a fix will only cause the save to fail with a better message. It won't tell you how to fix it.

So let's work on finding where the `__metadata` disappeared ... starting with whether it ever arrived in the first place.

I await your report.

### Update 17 July 2014

I'm still waiting to hear if you are seeing the `__metadata` property in the payload of the response to the original entity query.

Meanwhile, I checked the OData specs (plural) for references to the `__metadata` property. It appears that the `__metadata` property has always been optional. It follows that an OData provider need not send or honor the etag ... and we know that this is possible because Web API 2 OData didn't support etags ... a defect soon to be corrected.

> [See the OData v.2 spec where it describes JSON format](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/json-format/). Search for the term "__metadata".
>
> The OData v.3 spec also calls for the `__metadata` property in a JSON response (at least a JSON verbose response).
>
> But ... heavy sigh ... it appears that the `__metadata` property is gone from the v.4 spec and that the metadata information is supplied entirely through JSON annotations. The DataJS library (used by many but not all BreezeJS OData adapters) may map those annotations into the node's `__metadata` property but I can't confirm it yet. We have some work to do coping with all of these variations.

In the meanwhile, I think **all BreezeJS OData dataservice adapters should take a more defensive position regarding extra metadata and should simply ignore the omission rather than throw exceptions**.

We'll make these defensive changes very soon.

Of course the server will reject your update or delete request if the OData service actually requires an etag or other metadata. I don't know what we can do about that just yet.

Comment: Ward, I prematurely selected your response as an answer as I figured this would have been fixed the the version you mention at the top of your answer. But it seems like it is an issue in `BreezeJS 1.4.16` - I just checked the .12 release and experienced the same error. I am having the same problem as in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18513334/330430

Comment: Do you think I need to flag this question as a duplicate and maybe file a bug? I've used the workaround proposed in the question I mention in the comment above.

Comment: I just pointed that question back to here as I'm discussing it in more detail here. See also the update to my answer.

Comment: I do see the __metadata in the response from the SharePoint server. Using the suggestion by milunka below corrects the problem entirely for me.

Comment: I apologize that this is still floating out there. I've figured out what the problem is. If I am selecting too many fields from the SP list, the adapter is returning POJOs with no `__metadata` and since they are POJOs there is no entity aspect.

Comment: OK, it is not the number of fields. I'm still unsure of what is causing the problem but the SP DS adapter is returning POJOs not entities and they have no __metadata attribute either.

Answer (score 3):

There hasn't been a post in a while but I am going to share what I found as the problem and how I resolved it for me (because it took me a long time).

Basically the `breeze.labs.dataservice.sharepoint` adapter has a function `serverTypeNameToClientDefault()` that expects the SharePoint custom list type as returned by `REST/OData` in the __metadata "type" field to be in the **exact** format of:

```
SP.Data.**mylistname**sListItem**  (notice the "sListItem" suffix; ;  Ex. SP.Data.CustomersListItem)
```

This function does a string regex to extract the Breeze entity name from the SharePoint type and uses that name to look up the entity in the metadata store ("Customer" in the above example).  If there is no match, Breeze will not find your entity and will return a basic object instead of a Breeze entity.  Therefore your REST JSON result returned from SharePoint, even though it does have the __metadata property is not converted into a Breeze entity that contains the property `entityAspect.extraMetadata`, among other things.  This is what leads to the error "*Unable to get property 'type' of undefined or null reference*"

For my solution, since in my case I don't care as much what the URL of my custom lists are, I just made sure that when my custom list was provisioned by SharePoint that it resulted in a name according to what Breeze expects.  You accomplish this by setting the `Url` attribute of the `ListInstance` element like this:

```
<ListInstance 
      Title="My Customers" 
      OnQuickLaunch="TRUE" 
      TemplateType="10000" 
      Url="Lists/Customers"    <!-- List/Customer will not work -->
      Description="My List Instance">
      ...
```

The better solution would be to make the `serverTypeNameToClientDefault()` function more robust or fix it to my needs locally but hopefully this can be addressed in a future version of the adapter.

Note that I have tested this solution with the following configurations (not all dependencies listed):
Breeze.Client 1.4.9 with Breeze.DataService.SharePoint 0.2.3
Breeze.Client 1.5.0 with Breeze.DataService.SharePoint 0.3.2

Also note that the 0.3.2 version of the adapter now displays a better error message when this happens as mentioned above -- "*Missing the extra metadata for an update/delete entity*"; but it doesn't fix the problem.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and wondering if I should stick to the standard SharePoint JSOM stuff instead of the breeze approach. The code for Breeze is complex to follow, and it breaks at my first attempt to do something with it... Did you stick to it?

Answer (score 2):

For breeze v1.4.14 and breeze labs sharepoint 2013 v0.2.3 i am using small fix in file **breeze.labs.dataservice.sharepoint.js**.
At the end of function

```
function visitNode(node, mappingContext, nodeContext)
```

just before

```
return result;
```

i just set property extraMetadata like this:

```
result.extraMetadata = node.__metadata;
```

This seems to fix problem when i try to save modified entity back to sharepoint.

Comment: I don't see how this fixes the problem. "Papers it over" maybe but fixes it? What is the value of `node.__metadata` when you assign it to  `result.extraMetadata`? My bet is `null` ... which is unexpected. If it was non-null, the call to `updatedEntityNode` a few lines earlier should have done this. Would you please debug this and tell us what is happening as you move through `visitNode`. How does it skip the assignment within `updateEntityNode`?

Comment: As i saw it, problem was with saving loaded entities which doesnt contains property extraMetadata. My fix sets this property to loaded object with data from server. And node.__metadata isn't null, this property contains data from server (id, etag, type, uri).

Comment: I've got a visitor from out of the country with me so I'm not able to do the debugging myself. But I'll get to it first thing Monday morning.

Comment: I'm on vacation next week. We'll have to pick it up after that.

Comment: milunka - if `node.__metadata` isn't null, why isn't `updateEntityNode` setting `result.extraMetadata`? Perhaps because `node.$entityType` is undefined?  But if that's true, then the result won't have a `result.entityType` and Breeze won't think this is an entity. That means this would never go into cache (at least that's what I believe.) Is there `node.$type`. Maddening, isn't it?

Comment: Function updateEntityNode isn't setting property extraMetadata but it is setting property extra: `result.extra = node.__metadata;` Maybe I am using some old version of sharepoint breeze labs file?

Comment: I suffered the same problem. I debbuged the code, and node.__metadata contained the "missing" metadata, that is needed by the sharepoint-adapter. The adapter uses result.extreMetadata to set the metadata being send back to sharepoint. Maybe that's the real problem - maybe the sharepoint-adapter should use another property.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry folks for the long overdue aspect of this, but I got the bug with the extra "s" resolved today... FINALLY. You can track the issue here: https://github.com/andrewconnell/breeze.js.labs/issues/6

This all stemmed from a very incorrect assumption I made. It's been fixed in version 0.6.2 of the data service adapter for SharePoint. Note that you MUST use the same name for your entity when creating it in the metadata store as the list where the data is coming from.

Comment: I dropped this into a project I am working on right now and immediately got the error: `Missing the extra metadata for an update/delete entity` when I attempted to save. I've not had time to debug it at all so I cannot offer any more than that yet.

Comment: @RobertKaucher Did you apply the changes that I referenced in the issue above? Check this sample that reflects the changes I made to the project after updating it with the changes above. https://github.com/andrewconnell/sp-o365-rest/tree/master/BreezeSP2013Sample

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue with multiple `navigationProperties` on an entity by editing line 319 of `breeze.labs.dataservice.sharepoint.js v.0.10.0`

I changed:

```
if (entityType._mappedPropertiesCount <= Object.keys(node).length - 1)
```

to:

```
if (entityType.dataProperties.length <= Object.keys(node).length - 1)
```

It looks like the `_mappedPropertiesCount` includes the `navigationProperties` count too. e.g. `dataProperties.length + navigationProperties.length`

The query node was then thought to not contain a full set of properties for the entity (it was assumed to be the result of a partial projection).

It therefore wasn't being treated as an entity, its metadata wasn't being set, and it ultimately wasn't being added to the cache.

It worked with only one `navigationProperty` as there were two extra items in `Object.keys(node)`, __Metadata and ID. So it would still pass the test with one `navigationProperty`, but not two or more.